# New relic Maven exception

Tags: java, maven, newrelic

I´m using New relic on my Maven integration test, and sometimes when I run the integration test and my agent with the confirugraiton on the VM -javaagent:/path/to/newrelic.jar is running, I receive this exception

```
     ERROR: Aborted Maven execution for InterruptedIOException
     java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler$AcceptorImpl.accept(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:183)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:280)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:239)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Anyone know anything about this issue?

Regards.

Comment: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out`?

Comment: I know that sounds like he cannot reach a server, but just happens sometimes. I dont know if he cannot reach the new relic service or my application server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not see any indication of New Relic in your stack trace. Without looking at more detailed logging it is difficult to say if the agent is involved, however it looks a lot like this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5053

If you would like us to investigate further, please reach out to us at support.newrelic.com

Comment: I think you´re right my investigation was poiting to this issue now. It´s just that after add the new relic agent then sometimes start failing, I think that with the agent was too much.